# Circles and tangents and circumcircles

Tags: geometry, circles

Question:
Tangents drawn from the point $P(1, 8)$ to the circle $x^2 + y^2 -6x -4y -11=0$ touch the circle at the points $A$ and $B$. What is the equation of the circumcircle of the triangle $PAB$?

I tried drawing a diagram, and found the length of the tangent. However, I lost as to where to proceed from there. Please help me!

Comment: Ooops. Sorry, I wrote the wrong equation. Edited the correct one! @Semiclassical

Comment: Well, you may observe the answer that the line joining P and and the Centre of the given circle (C) is diameter. PABC form a cyclic quadrilateral and centre of the circle is mid point of P and C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The usual way to construct tangents to a circle around $C$ through a point $P$ is to draw a circle with diameter $CP$, and intersect that with the original circle.  Any triangle made from three points on a circle has that circle as a circumcircle.

Comment: Awesome. I had an inkling about the fact that CP might be the diameter, but had no concrete proof. Thanks!

Comment: @Gummybears For proof take the angle in a semicircle is a right-angle in the circle with diameter $CP$